# Getting error code 103 when updating HMS Core APK while using HMS Video Kit

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I'm using HMS Video Kit Version **com.huawei.hms:videokit-player:1.0.1.300**.
After SDK integration when loading the main page it ask to update HMS Core APK. But while updating it gives the error **103** or get error code **100** and failed to play the given video URL.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason**

The error code 100 means Video Kit (APK) needs to be downloaded.

**Solution**

Please do the check as follows:

1). Currently, Huawei Video Kit **1.0.1.300** supports Chinese mainland, Hong Kong(China), Singapore, India and Turkey. Please check the region where your HUAWEI ID was registered. You can go to **Me** > **Settings** on AppGallery to find the region.

2). Check whether HMS Core (APK) has been updated to the latest version. Supported Devices are:
Device Brand: Huawei
Device Type: Phone or tablet
HMS Core (APK) Version: 5.0.0.300 or later

About failed to play the given video URL, here are the Use Cases: You can integrate the Video Kit WisePlayer SDK into your app so that it can play streaming media from a third-party video address. Streaming media must be in 3GP, MP4, or TS format and comply with HTTP/HTTPS, HLS, or DASH. Currently, it cannot play local video.

To give more precise solution I need to see the code parts of the program.
For more information, please visit [Huawei Video Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/introduction-0000001050439577-V5).